# Using Move-It IK outside of ROS (Unity3d)

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, move-group-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

Unsure whether this is even possible or not but just wondering if anyone has tried using the Move-It planning libraries outside of ROS? Specifically looking at trying to import them into Unity3d in order to simulate an industrial robot?

Does anyone have any idea where I could start with this or any other ideas? I have the robot working in ROS with move it planning and really like the IK and obstacle detection aspects and so would like to use this in Unity for a specific application.

Thanks,
Callum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288885/using-move-it-ik-outside-of-ros-(unity3d)/) by [callum91](https://answers.ros.org/users/33701/callum91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-04-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're just looking for kinematic playout (ie: visualisation), then perhaps the infrastructure in [siemens/ros-sharp](https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp) could be sufficient (urdf loader, trajectory/JointState visualisation, etc).

If you're actually looking for full use of MoveIt (ie: planning, sensor integration, etc) with Unity, that might get a bit involved, but parts of that could still be done with `ros-sharp` I imagine.

Most (if not all) of MoveIt's planning capabilities can be interacted with via topics, services and actions, and those should be accessible through `ros-sharp` as well. Making sense of / visualising the results returned by MoveIt though is something that you'll probably have to implement yourself.

---

Edit: if you're just after using the IK solvers directly (so not the planning facilities) then those are essentially C++ classes, so not sure how to integrate those directly without some effort. MoveIt does expose both FK and IK services which should be accessible using `ros-sharp` though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-17**:\

> Move-It planning libraries [..] to simulate an industrial robot?

And pedantic maybe, but MoveIt is not a simulator.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-17**:
Also note: there are more rosbridge-c-sharp/unity integrations available. I only mentioned `ros-sharp` as it already includes infrastructure to load urdfs and visualise trajectories etc.